# Сложение всех элементов массива

Tags: php, c#, массивы, алгоритм, delphi

Нужно решить следующую задачу:

> Имеется массив, содержащий произвольные числа:
>   [3], [5], [2], [6] ....
>   Нужно найти суммы всех возможных сложений его элементов и записать их в другой массив. Т.е. получается если в массиве 4 элемента, другой массив должен состоять из 16.

Как реализовать алгоритм?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То есть вам нужно получить все возможные подмножества данного множества.

Самый простой вариант - для множества из `N` элементов берем число из `N` битов, и проходим по всем возможным значениям числа (для 4 элементов - от 0000 до 1111, т.е. от 0 до 15). Далее для каждого числа суммируем элементы, соответствующие единицам - типа, для 0011 - третий и четвертый (понятно, что удобнее и логичнее считать с младших битов, так что нулевой и первый :))

Думаю, перевести на конкретный язык проблем не составит.

Если задача конкретно в суммах - то я бы смотрел на [**коды Грея**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F), тогда каждое следующее значение получается путем прибавления или вычитания только одного элемента.